# dplyr object not found i

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling

I'm trying to put lines to show the `mean` + `sd` on my graph, but I keep getting the same error code:

> "Error in mean(NoHealthInsurance) : object 'NoHealthInsurance' not
> found".

Do I have a parenthesis in the wrong place or something?

```
hist <- ggplot(data = west) +
  geom_histogram(aes(NoHealthInsurance), 
                 color = wes_palette("Zissou1", 1), 
                 fill = wes_palette("Zissou1", 2)[2]) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(NoHealthInsurance))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(NoHealthInsurance) - sd(NoHealthInsurance)), color = "blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(NoHealthInsurance) + sd(NoHealthInsurance)), color = "blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(NoHealthInsurance) - 2*sd(NoHealthInsurance)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(NoHealthInsurance) + 2*sd(NoHealthInsurance)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted")
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with your data because you didn't provide any example data, but the code below works with mtcars. Basically you need to add a reference of your data in the `mean()` and `sd()` functions, like `.data$variable`. See below.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(aes(mpg)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(mtcars$mpg))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(mtcars$mpg) - sd(mtcars$mpg)), color = "blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(mtcars$mpg) + sd(mtcars$mpg)), color = "blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(mtcars$mpg) - 2*sd(mtcars$mpg)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (mean(mtcars$mpg) + 2*sd(mtcars$mpg)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted")
```

[image: hist]